# Is it possible to customize a repo's creation date in Github?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to push some old projects of mine to Github, and I'd like to associate them with some approximate creation dates. I know how to backdate the commits, but it is driving me crazy that I can't get the repo creation date to match. Is there any way to backdate the actual date of the repo's creation (when it was created on github.com)? I was hoping this might be an option with the Github API.